# Posting JSON array in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, json

How can we post following json array in sql server using c#?

```
{
    "sname" : ["<font color='red'> AneeshYadav </font>", "<font color='red'> AdityaMadan </font>", "<font color='red'> DrishtiThakur </font>", "<font color='red'> IshaanSahay </font>"],
    "admno" : ["1357", "1414", "1442", "4184"],
    "class" : ["1795", "1795", "1795", "1795"],
    "sms" : ["0", "1", "1", "1"],
    "att" : ["Not Posted", "Not Posted", "Not Posted", "Not Posted"],
    "tra" : ["on", "on", "on", "on"]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to convert table data to JSON?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I insert four objects in SQL?" or "How can I insert this JSON array as a string to an SQL?"

Comment: i want it to be inserted in sql?

Comment: @AmazingAshu the whole Json array in string format? Or do you want the data formatted and inserted to the DB as 4 individual rows??

Comment: I wonder how you created this JSON in SQL? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

> Note that varchar field has a size of 8000 character max. As of 2005
>   varchar(MAX) can be used which (by msdn) claims to be 2^31-1 which is
>   2147483647 (2.14 billion). However, you need to use special indexing
>   if you want to use keywords `contains` and  `like`.

However it will be way more efficient to use Mongo, Redis, Raven instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way but hopefully it will help. Convert the json string to a DataTable ( mainly for the structure). Then iterate through the data in the datatable and save it to the db.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = "...<json data>...";
// Convert to DataTable.
// Deserialize the JSon value and assign it to datatable      
DataTable dtValue = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,typeof(DataTable)));
```

Just a note as well, check your json object formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Sql Server 2016 CTP3 you can use OPENJSON see [Import JSON in Sql Server 2016](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2015/09/22/openjson-the-easiest-way-to-import-json-text-into-table.aspx)